# Swift Notification is sent but not received

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, nsnotificationcenter, notificationcenter

I added an observer to be notified when a charger is connected.

```
CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(
  CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(),
  nil,
  { (_, _, _, _, _) in
    print("Sending...")
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "test123"), object: nil)
  },
  kIOPSNotifyAttach as CFString?,
  nil, 
  .deliverImmediately
)
```

When the charger is connected the a notification is sent so that I can react in my application.
So I added an observer in my app

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
  self,
  selector: #selector(reactToNotification(_:)),
  name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "test123"),
  object: nil)
```

The notification is sent correctly but the associated function is never called.

```
@objc func reactToNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
    print("Receiving...")
}
```

Is there a specific problem in my concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really mismatch issue

- You sent this notification `NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "test123")`
- But expected to get this: `NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "test")`

It's just naming issue!

Comment: OK, this was unexpected and embarrassing :D Thanks!